# Rename field in SHP file (DBF) with ArcCatalog

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.2, fields-attributes, arccatalog

I want to rename some fileds on a SHP file, (the fields on the DBF file), using ArcCatalog (**ArcGIS Desktop v10.2.2**).

From ArcCatalog, right click on a SHP file -> `Properties...` -> `Fields`.
Then the program let you rename the field and change the data type... apparently.

[image: Shapefile Properties]

When I hit `Enter` or click `Apply`, an error appears: **Failed to alter the name of the field.**

The file is not in use, nor read only, and the name of the field is under the 10 character limit.

Ironically, I can do it with gvSIG!

Comment: I've experienced the same problem, and I've ended up creating a new shapefile with the right field names, joined and copied the value

Comment: You simply can't. This is arcgis limitation. Use Merge tool to rename the field name and recreate the whole shapefile (Easiest approach!).